# Who were the witches whom Indra crushed to death?

Tags: vedas, puranas, rig-veda, indra

Rigved [Verse 1.133](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01133.htm) mentions this curious story:

> 1. WITH sacrifice I purge both earth and heaven: I burn up **great she-fiends** who serve not Indra, Where throttled by thy hand the foes were slaughtered, and in the pit of death lay pierced and mangled.
> 2. O thou who castest forth the stones crushing the sorceresses’ heads,
>      Break them with thy wide-spreading foot, with thy wide-spreading mighty foot.
> 3. Do thou, O Maghavan, beat off **these sorceresses'** daring strength.
>      Cast them within the narrow pit. within the deep and narrow pit.

My question is who were these she-fiends or sorceresses? Is this event mentioned in any other scripture in detail?

Answer (score 1):

**Well, the alternate translations don't use the word 'witches' or 'she-fiends'.**

The Original Verses are-

> उ॒भे पु॑नामि॒ रोद॑सी ऋ॒तेन॒ द्रुहो॑ दहामि॒ सं म॒हीर॑नि॒न्द्राः ।
> अ॒भि॒व्लग्य॒ यत्र॑ ह॒ता अ॒मित्रा॑ वैलस्था॒नं परि॑ तृ॒ळ्हा अशे॑रन् ॥
> १.१३३.०१
>
> अ॒भि॒व्लग्या॑ चिदद्रिवः शी॒र्षा या॑तु॒मती॑नाम् । 
>  छि॒न्धि
> व॑टू॒रिणा॑ प॒दा म॒हाव॑टूरिणा प॒दा ॥ १.१३३.०२ ॥
>
> अवा॑सां मघवञ्जहि॒ शर्धो॑ यातु॒मती॑नाम् ।
>  वै॒ल॒स्था॒न॒के अ॑र्म॒के
> म॒हावै॑लस्थे अर्म॒के ॥ १.१३३.०३ ॥

Consider the following translators.

#### 1. [Dr. Tulsi Ram](https://archive.org/details/susmitaroychowdhury512_gmail/%E0%A6%8B%E0%A6%97%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%A6/page/n637/mode/2up?view=theater)

> 1. I purify the earth and heavens both by the light of truth and the fire and fragrance of yajna, creative and cooperative action. I
>    subject **the elements of hate and chaos** to the heat and power of
>    law and discipline and bum off the anti-Indra forces on earth to
>    naught. And having thus seized and **crushed the unfriendly elements**
>    wherever they happen to be active, and confirmed that they are dead
>    and gone, I let them lie asleep in their grave.
> 2. Indra, lord of yajna, power and law, firm as rock and generous as cloud, having caught the lawless and the violent by the head of the
>    evil-minded, crush them under the wide wide foot, crush them by the
>    rising forces of the youth.
> 3. Indra, maghavan, lord of world power and wealth, break down and destroy the **force of the evil-minded** and throw them out deep into
>    the vault of darkness, into the hideous world of sin and death.

---

#### 2.  [H.H. Wilson](https://archive.org/details/RigVedaSanhitaByHHWilsonVol2/page/n55/mode/2up?view=theater)

> 1. By sacrifice I purify both the heaven and the earth: I burn the wide (realms of earth) that are without Inbra, and are (the haunts) of
>    **the wicked** : wherever **the enemies** have congregated they have been
>    slain : and, utterly destroyed, they sleep in a deep pit.
> 2. Devourer (of foes), having trampled on the heads of the malignant (hosts), crush them with thy wide-spreading foot ; thy vast
>    wide-spreading foot.
> 3. Annihilate, Maghavan, the might of **malignant (hoots)**, hurl them into the vile pit ; the vast and vile pit.

---

#### 3. [M.N. Dutt](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.532568/page/n356/mode/1up?view=theater)

> 1. By sacrifice I purify both the sky and the earth I burn the wide (realms of Earth) that are without Indra and are (the haunts) of **the
>    wicked**, wherever **the enemies** have congregated they have been slain:
>    and utterly destroyed, they sleep in a dip pit.
> 2. Devourer (of enemies) having trampled on the heads pL[the malignant (hosts)* crush them with thy wide-spreading foot; thy vast
>    wide-spreading foot.
> 3. Crush, Maghavan, the power of **malignant (hosts)** hurl them into the vile pit; the vast and vile pit.

---

#### 4. Other Hindi Translators' views:-

- Pandit [ShriRam Sharma](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v2.90) Acharya (from the Gayatri Parivaar):

  - He translates the words as the enemies of Indra or terrible people who revolt and oppose the dominance of Indra.

- [Ramgovind Trivedi](https://archive.org/details/Rigveda.In.Hindi.by.Ramgovind.Trivedi_201512/page/n352/mode/1up):

  - He also interprets them as enemies or adversaries of Indra, in general, who are violent and antagonistic.

---

#### 5. An allegorical exposition:

- Pandit Jaydev Sharma, [in his Hindi commentary (*bhashya*)](https://archive.org/details/FourVedas-SanskritTextWithHindiCommentaryByPanditJaydevSharma/RigVedSanhitaBhashaBhashya-jaydevSharmaVol21940/page/n75/mode/2up) on the same interprets it in two ways.

  - (i). The **normal interpretation** is similar to previous Hindi translators viz. enemies or rebellious elements challenging Indra's sovereignity.
  - (ii). From a **spiritual perspective**, he interprets it as the inner enemies of Humans, the feelings of lust & desire, anger, etc i.e., the feeling & emotions (*vasanaas* & *vrittis*) that the counter-intuitive to the spiritual well-being & upliftment of a *jiva*.

---

## To conclude:

- We'd be hard-pressed to find any "detailed story" in this regard since there might not be one to start with, it (the use of the word "she-fiends" or "sorceresses") all seems a play of translation. But it does have a higher spiritual or metaphorical interpretation as evident above under the '5th Heading'.